# Run a program in another language in linux

Tags: linux, bash, multilingual, archlinux

How would you go about running a program to output it's text in a foreign language? I'm running KDE Arch linux and am trying to run pacman to output it's text in Dutch but can't seem to get it to work. I've tried

```
LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 sudo pacman -Syy
KDE_LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 sudo pacman -Syy
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you're trying to set `LANG` or `KDE_LANG` would set those variables for `sudo` and not the command that you're attempting to execute.

Instead say:

```
sudo LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 pacman -Syy
```

or

```
sudo KDE_LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 pacman -Syy
```

---

Quoting `man sudo`:

```
   sudo [-AbEHnPS] [-C fd] [-g group name|#gid] [-p prompt] [-r role]
   [-t type] [-u user name|#uid] [VAR=value] [-i | -s] [command]

   ...

   Environment variables to be set for the command may also be passed on
   the command line in the form of VAR=value, ...
```

Comment: Hmm... that's still not working.

Comment: Variables passed on the command line are subject to the same restrictions as normal environment variables.

Comment: @josh Are you able to run `pacman` in your desired locale without using `sudo`?

Comment: No, there's still no change when removing sudo. I've also tried uncommenting my desired locale in `/etc/locale.gen` and then running `locale-gen` and it still didn't work.

Comment: @josh That seems to indicate that the program you're trying to execute doesn't support localization, _perhaps_.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I've seen people having pacman output in many different languages, as well as a qoute from the developer Allan Mcrae saying pacman had now been translated to over 20 languages. I can't seem to get it to output in any of them though. This might be a program with my setup, and not my running the command wrong though, so perhaps I should put this on unix and linux.

Answer (score 0):

Sudo discsrds most environment as it's a security risk.

You need to either edit your security policy (see man sudo, man sudoers) to allow passing LANG and/or KDE_LANG, or run the command explicitly via a shell and set the environment in the shell (the easiest way is to wrap the command in a shell script).

Comment: n.m. For Arch, pacman is the package manager, usually needing root.

Comment: Ahh, not the game. Funny, that.